# Deny Access to AWS Console if not in IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'd like to deny access to AWS console if a user is outside of our network or VPN. I found this policy but I'm running into random issues where a user gets an explicit deny even though they are in the network and have AdministratorAccess attached. It should be noted that I am using role based access through Okta.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOutOfOffice",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "<insert IP>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You might be able to use **AWS CloudTrail** to diagnose the rejection issues.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Okta IP address?

Comment: Okta IP address? Okta has many IP addresses that are used. The request is coming from one public IP not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. This is related to AWS making internal calls using their internal IP and systems which naturally will cause an error due to my policy. The only work around at this time is to whitelist the specific services that use AWS's internal servers..

Comment: As of Jun 2022, there is a AWS global condition context key of [aws:ViaAWSService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-viaawsservice) which can accommodate the check for AWS internal calls.